# Широтно-импульсная модуляция (PWM) в чем измеряется

Tags: железо, пк

Всем привет , собственно вопрос такой , для изменении скорости вращения вентилятора  мы  меняем файл pwm (0-255) ,что является регулировкой питания ,которое подается на вентилятор.

---

Вопрос в том , почему именно от 0 до 255 и в чем это измеряется (какие единицы измерения), не могу нагуглить ответ на этом вопрос.

Comment: По-русски это называется "скважность". А диапазон 0-255 потому что (как тут уже сказали) в Вашем случае счетчик ШИМ восьмибитный. Это никакие не единицы измерения в физическом смысле. Это процент заполнения. Просто 255 единиц это максимум, а 0 это минимум. Все остальное можно пересчитать в процентах от максимума. То есть 128 единиц это половина подводимой мощности. Но нужно еще учитывать, что характеристика мощности самого вентилятора может быть нелинейной и половина подводимой мощности вовсе не означает половинную мощность потока воздуха.

Comment: Выражаясь строго, это не скважность. Скважность меняется от 1 до бесконечности. А это - смасштабированный коэффициент заполнения, который меняется от 0 до 1.

Answer (score 2):

Измеряется в процентах. Почему 255? Видимо в данном случае 255 соответствует 100%.
Счётчик 8 битный.

Answer (score 0):

Импульсная модуляция (любая) ни в чем не измеряется, на сколько я помню. Это способ "посадить" полезный сигнал в более высокую частоту. По поводу ШИМ в вентиляторах, выдержка из рандомной статьи:

> PWM представляет собой систему контроля уровня питания, подаваемого на
>   электромотор вентилятора, посредством изменения относительной ширины
>   импульсов в цепи

То есть мы можем, меняя ширину сигнала, влиять на скорость вращения. Про потолок в 255 нашел статью - http://arduino.ru/Tutorial/PWM. Да и вообще, 255 это вроде максимум в 8-битной системе.

Answer (score 0):

Это совершенно произвольное безразмерное значение. С таким же успехом это может быть `0..1000` или `0..65535`. Значение `0` вызывает остановку электродвигателя (коэффициент заполнения = `0.0`), максимальное значение `255` (или `1000`, или `65535`) вызывает подачу немодулированного напряжения питания (коэффициент заполнения = `1.0`). Промежуточные значения диапазона естественным линейным образом отображаются на промежуточные значения коэффициента заполнения.

Таким образом использование более широкого диапазона приводит лишь к увеличению точности контроля над коэффициентом заполнения. Для целей управления вентилятором точности в 256 шагов более чем достаточно. Хватило бы и 16, или даже 8.